# Not sure why my div is not showing validation messages

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

Ello stack, Cant seem to figure out why there isn't any text showing in my div after validation of a field. Here is my code. I know that the validation is running but, I'm not sure why my validation message isn't showing up in the div.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:62147/Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        "use strict";
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#testerbtn").bind("click", function () {
                alert("onclick is fired");
                $("#myform").validate({
                    errorLabelContainer: $("#Errors"),
                    rules: {
                        textToVal: { required: true }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        textToVal: "the field is required! nub~!"
                    }
                });
                alert("validation should have happend.");

            })
        });

    </script>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id = "myform" action="htmlPage1.htm">
         <div id="Errors"></div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="textToVal"  value="" />
            <input type="button" id="testerbtn"  value="Tester" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does `.validate()` have a callback?

Comment: Are you sure validation is running? Because if this is copy-pasted, you have `"use strict";` randomly placed at the beginning of your script.

Comment: `"use scrict"` is not a random string. Read about strict mode here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of things I see here that could be causing issues:

1. Ensure your `input`s have `name` attributes:

   ```
   <input type="text" id="textToVal"  value="" name="textToVal" />
   ```
2. `validate()` should be instantiated **outside** of your click handler. Additionally, change your `button` type to `submit` to automatically trigger the validation code.

In summary:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myform").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: $("#Errors"),
        rules: {
            textToVal: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            textToVal: "the field is required! nub~!"
        }
    });
});
```

**Html:**

```
<form id = "myform" action="htmlPage1.htm">          
    <div id="Errors"></div>         
    <div>             
        <input type="text" id="textToVal"  value="" name="textToVal" />             
        <input type="submit" id="testerbtn"  value="Tester" />         
    </div>     
</form>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fJ8XF/

Comment: It was #2 on your list. Thx u much.

Answer (score 0):

HI Terrance,

I believe `errorLabelContainer` is meant to be a selector (string), so you should use 
"`#Errors`" instead of `$('#Errors')`

Comment: Tried this `errorLabelContainer: #Errors,` and got an invalid character error.